# Rollback error received when attempting to connect sqlalchemy to an existing postgres database

Tags: postgresql, jupyter-notebook, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to use jupyter notebook to build a simple data visualization app for data that I have in an existing postgresql database.

This tutorial is the guideline for what I am attempting to achieve: https://github.com/nihalsahan/DB/blob/main/ConnectPostgres.ipynb

I followed all the steps listed therein, but I receive an error on the fifth line.

Here is my code:

Input:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://postgres:asdf@localhost:5432/test_cpp')
engine.connect()
```

Output:

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection at 0x7fab840c9d90>
```

Input:

```
%load_ext sql
```

Output:

```
The sql extension is already loaded. To reload it, use:
  %reload_ext sql
```

Input:

```
%sql $engine.url
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 903, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sql/magic.py", line 196, in execute
    conn = sql.connection.Connection.set(
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sql/connection.py", line 70, in set
    cls.current = existing or Connection(descriptor, connect_args, creator)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sql/connection.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.internal_connection = engine.connect()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3264, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2426, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3288, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 903, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/bluesanta/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

I have looked through the traceback errors and attempted to isolate the issue, but have not found success.

One of the errors is the password authentication error, but this does not seem to be an issue in a separate app (written in C++) that I wrote that uses the same password to connect to the database.

I have installed `psychopg2-binary`.

There are several similar errors on stackoverflow and elsewhere online, but I have not found any that specifically deal with this simple `%sql $engine.url` issue.

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong? Thank you.